# disable GNOME screensaver screenlock in rhel/centos 7

Tags: gnome, gnome3, screen-lock, screensaver

running RHEL 7.9, with the installation of it as **Server with GUI**.  My [work] operating environment is the server is in a server room and all users connect to it over the network using VNC.

Problem I have as an admin is I can connect into their existing VNC session, with the intent to close it out cleanly prior to doing a reboot... when the user is on travel and leaves an empty vnc session active but I don't know until I connect into it.

But when I do connect into it I hit the GNOME *console* screen lock within the VNC session, and I don't know the user's password to unlock it...

How in RHEL 7.9 do I **globally** disable all screen lock and screen savers so that all users will never have a screen saver or screen lock automatically kick in?  Preferably I also don't want any user to be able to turn such a thing back on for themself.  It is a basic *server with gui* installation of RHEL 7.9 using the standard GNOME *desktop environment / graphical user interface* .  I am not using KDE or XFCE or anything like that.

Comment: Can you add your desktop environment (e.g. Gnome) to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

Using [redhat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/desktop_migration_and_administration_guide/custom-default-values-system-settings) as reference.

Create the `user` profile in `/etc/dconf/profile/user` if it does not already exist:

```
user-db:user
system-db:local
```

Edit `/etc/dconf/db/local.d/00-screensaver`

If there is already a section with the heading: `[org/gnome/desktop/screensaver]` then just edit/add: `lock-enabled=false` underneath that heading. If there is not, then create it:

```
[org/gnome/desktop/screensaver]
lock-enabled=false
```

Edit `/etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/screensaver` (create it if it doesn't exist):
Add the following line to the file:

```
/org/gnome/desktop/screensaver/lock-enabled
```

This will lock the setting so that users cannot change it.

Run `dconf update` to update the system databases.

Users may need to restart their gnome session for the change to be picked up.

Comment: the `/etc/dconf/db/local.d/00-screensaver` setting`lock-enabled=false` and `idle-activation-enabled=false` under  `[org/gnome/desktop/screensaver]` within the file, follwed by a `dconf update` seemed to do the trick.